# PostgreSQL: How and Why does the WAL (Write-Ahead Log) Grow?

Tags: postgresql, wal

I have a problem with the growing number of WAL files, and they just keep increasing. How can I influence this? I have already deleted old transactions and unnecessary replication slots, which slightly reduced the number and size of WAL files, but it is still a lot.

Archiving is not enabled.

The PostgreSQL server is a physical server with sufficient disk resources, and there are no bottlenecks. It's just that the number of WAL files keeps increasing and not getting deleted.

I have already deleted old transactions and unnecessary replication slots.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow and should be posted on https://dba.stackexchange.com. Good news is you are more likely to find help there (a question on that topic may even already exist).

Comment: I collected all possible reasons in [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/why-does-my-pg_wal-keep-growing/). If you can exclude archiving and replication slots (double-check!), it can only be a large `wal_keep_size`. To be sure, run `CHECKPOINT` as superuser - if that does not reduce the size, it must be one of those problems.